# I need the basename + extension of a file in a relative path in an environment variale

Tags: windows-10

I need the basename + extension of a file in a relative path in an environment variale. Eg: if I type in the argument `..\..\Appdata\bin\test.jpg` the resulting environmental var should contain `test.jpg`. If I type an argument of the bat sript like `sub1\sub2\input.png`, it should contain `input.png`. This can be done with a for statement, with `delims=\`, and choosing for the LAST field. I don't know how to select the last field.

Answer (score 1):

In the post
[Batch Extract path and filename from a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567809/batch-extract-path-and-filename-from-a-variable)
is found this script for extracting all the file-parts from an environment
variable:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set file=C:\Users\l72rugschiri\Desktop\fs.cfg
FOR %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
ECHO filedrive=%%~di
ECHO filepath=%%~pi
ECHO filename=%%~ni
ECHO fileextension=%%~xi
)
```

And the complete list for extracting information from the first parameter
of the `.bat` script:

```
%~1 - expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~f1 - expands %1 to a fully qualified path name
%~d1 - expands %1 to a drive letter only
%~p1 - expands %1 to a path only
%~n1 - expands %1 to a file name only
%~x1 - expands %1 to a file extension only
%~s1 - expanded path contains short names only
%~a1 - expands %1 to file attributes
%~t1 - expands %1 to date/time of file
%~z1 - expands %1 to size of file
```

Which may be used, for example:

```
set file=%~f1
set filepath=%~dp1
set filename=%~nx1
```

Or as a local FOR variable:

```
for %%a in (..\Desktop\fs.cfg) do (
    set file=%%~fa
    set filepath=%%~dpa
    set filename=%%~nxa
)
```